# Change imeAction to custom string in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, keyboard, android-jetpack-compose

I want to change imeAction to e.g. OK

```
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
    keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword,
    imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
),
```

This is the current state. I tried with imeActionLabel = "OK", but read somewhere that it is not possible to use it in the new compose. This is in BasicTextField